# "Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project"

Tags: android-studio, gradle

A pesar de haber desactivado el modo offline del gradle me sigue dando el mismo error al hacer el "build".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mis archivo Gradle Proyect settings es este:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
rootProject.name = "Vinder"
include ':app'
```

El error viene de la línea del Gradle Module App:

```
implementation 'com.github.dhaval2404:imagepicker-support:1.7.1'
```

Y el error es este:

> No cached version of com.github.dhaval2404:imagepicker-support:1.7.1
> available for offline mode. Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync
> project

Comment: Por favor agrega el error a tu pregunta. Puedes hacer click en [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Si obtienes el error:

" No cached version of com.github.dhaval2404:imagepicker-support:1.7.1 available for offline mode. Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project "

Debes desactivar el modo offline de `Gradle`, no debe estar seleccionado el botón que indicas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero recuerda que es importante ahora sincronizar los archivos `gradle` con tu proyecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si continuas teniendo problemas, debes revisar tu conexión a internet y si [el repositorio de la biblioteca](https://github.com/Dhaval2404/ImagePicker) existe.

Comment: Sí sí, lo he hecho, y me sigue dando error, lo extraño es que el error es diferente ahora que hace diez minutos: "Could not GET 'https://jitpack.io/com/github/dhaval2404/imagepicker-support/1.7.1/imagepicker-support-1.7.1.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project"

Comment: Qué error es ahora? @JavierOrtegaGarcía

Comment: seguramente sea cosa del repositorio o algo, no sé

Comment: @JavierOrtegaGarcía en tu settings.gradle tendrás configurado:  startParameter.offline=true?

Comment: No, también he intentado poner startParameter.offline=false, tampoco funciona

Answer (score 0):

El implementation estaba mal, hay que usar este:

```
implementation 'com.github.Dhaval2404:ImagePicker:v2.1'
```

Y en el gradle settings poner esto:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        jcenter()
    }
}
```